# Need help with setting vlans(is it possible?)

Tags: cisco, vlan

I have network like this:
[image]

i have 2 problems:

## a) how to create connection in vlans between 2 hosts in diffrent networks?

## b) how i can set vlan 4 to be seen  by rest vlans(1,2,3) but 1,2,3 must be separated.

sorry for my english btw :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

a) Two hosts in the same VLAN should be able to talk to each other - when more than a single switch is involved, this requires proper setup of the links (=VLAN trunks) between them. Communication between two VLANs needs to be routed (either with a dedicated router or a layer-3 switch). This assumes that the hosts in question belong to the same IP subnet. Different subnets require routing in between, regardless of VLAN membership.

b) This needs to be set up on the router. Depending on its capabilities, this can be done with firewall-style policies ("permit traffic from VLAN 4 to VLANs 1,2,3") or (with a layer-3 switch) through ACL rules. Note that ACL rules are stateless, so depending on where they are applied, you might need to permit traffic in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to communicate between two VLANs, you need a router (a layer 3 device).

Remember that layer 2 addresses (MAC addresses) are local only to the VLAN.  To communicate with another VLAN, you need layer 3 (IP) addresses.  A router can forward traffic based on layer 3 addresses.  A switch cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this requirement until and unless router is deployed in setup . Because by default same Vlan hosts can talk to each other without any routing .

But to ensure communication between different Vlans routing is required to enable routing layer3 devices is mandatory . inter-Vlan routing need to configure on router by creating sub -interfaces or if device you choose is layer3 switch then SVI can be configured enabling "IP routing"